# Convert formatting tabs to spaces in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before someone tries to mark this as a duplicate, DON'T.  Please read the question very carefully.  I've seen similar questions asked (and answered incorrectly).

I am using Visual Studio Code.  I have code that has used tabs WITHIN A LINE, not just at the beginning, to format columns.  I am trying, unsuccessfully, to convert those tabs to the appropriate number of spaces to maintain the columns.

Before you suggest ctrl-shift-I, that only works on LEADING tabs, not those within the line.
Also, don't suggest the "Untabify" or similar extensions.  Those only convert every tab to 4 (or however many) spaces without determining how many spaces would be appropriate to maintain the tab stops.

Visual Studio 2008 had an "untabify" function that would do exactly what I am looking for.  It doesn't seem to have been carried over to VSCode.

Thanks,
Greg
Thanks.

Comment: Did they use '\t' or actually hit the tab key for visual alignment?

Comment: It is actual tab characters (\t) as when the editor is set to insert tabs when the tab key is pressed.  This is actually my preferred setting because it makes formatting code so much cleaner, but alas this organization wants all spaces and I have a lot of legacy code that does things both ways.

Comment: If VS offers what you want, why not pop the code in there and do it? What you're describing sounds odd to me. Even with tabs within a line, they should all be the same size, and VS Code can replace ALL tabs with spaces as I'm sure you've seen. If they really need to be variable, that sounds like bad practice and you'd need to refactor anyway. Or at least run it through clang-format. If ti's literal `\t`s for printing, and VS Code doesn't have an extension, then it's time for the big brother to step in and take care of business.

Comment: Since I am using Linux, loading up Visual Studio is not an option.  Tabs were used to format the code in columns.  It is standard practice for readability and is even called out in some coding standards like BARR:2018.  Look at Visual Studio 2008 (probably later too).  There is a built-in menu option to reformat a section of code to convert multiple spaces to the appropriate number of tab characters and to convert code that used tabs to align columns to tab stops into spaces.  That functionality is all I am asking for.

Comment: This comment makes it sound like the built-in behavior that VS Code possesses is sufficient. Without a code example, I don't think anyone will be able to help you any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the meantime, someone created the extension  which solves your problem:

https://github.com/dmfabritius/untabify

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Another solution which does not involve an extension:

1. Convert your file to space indentation using the command "Convert to space indentation". It will change all the tabs at the beginning of the lines to space.
2. Select one of the remaining tab, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all occurences.
3. Press <kbd>tab</kbd>. All the tabs should be replaced with the correct number of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

None of "untabify" extension do not work as I expect.
"Edit with Shell Command" extension with "expand" command works.

Answer (score -1):

Do a search for Regex's `\t` and replace with your wanted number of spaces?

[image]

Comment: That's not what is wanted.  I can easily do a global search and replace all tabs with 4 spaces.  The problem is that destroys the entire concept of tab stops for columnar formatting.  What I need is something that will globally replace tab characters with the correct number of spaces (1, 2, 3 or 4) to keep the code aligned along tab stops.  This is the "Untabify" command in Visual Studio 2008.