# Why my terminal says indentation error when I do not have anything unindented?

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation

im running my code on a virtual environment and i have installed all libraries.

Here is the error:

[image: error]

and this is my code:

```
import cv2
import dlib
import time
import threading
import math

carCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('myhaar.xml')
video = cv2.VideoCapture('cars.mp4')

while True:
        ret,image=video.read()
        cv2.imshow("frame",image)
        if((cv2.waitKey(1)) & 0xFF ==ord('q')):
                 break
video.release()
video.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it's easier for everyone when you post the code instead of just screenshots.

Comment: [tab vs. space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034637/convert-formatting-tabs-to-spaces-in-vs-code)

Comment: Did you by any chance mix tabs and spaces? Your editor *should* be configured to expand all tabs to exactly four spaces, but many people don't do that properly.

Comment: Yup, source view shows you've got a tab on the `ret,image=video.read()` line.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it did work when i checked for tabs. Thanks

Comment: I know it's not the question but the break is a bad practice I suggest making a var True and doing while var

Comment: @OlauPla: `break` is perfectly fine.

Comment: We should not discuss it here but no its not perfectly fine

Comment: Can you tell me why var true would be better?

Comment: @Shailly: There's no reason it's better; Python doesn't have a `do`/`while` construct, and if your code is in fact `do`/`while` in nature (always executes once), it's perfectly reasonable to handle it with an infinite loop that has an option to `break` at the end. There are cases where people use `break`s unnecessarily when a plain `while cond:` is simpler, but those cases typically include the possibility of failing to execute the loop even once; in this case, a flag variable is not superior, and it's arguably inferior (smearing the logic for ending the loop all over, vs. localizing to end).

Comment: In practice, I rarely see code *improved* by the use of flag variables; either they test the condition directly (and don't need a flag), or they determine when they need to stop at the point they might otherwise set a flag and just stop then with `break` rather than setting a flag. Flag variables are almost always an ugly hack to enable multilevel `break`s.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an extra space on the line with `break` (I count 9 spaces whereas the other indents are using 8 spaces)

Comment: vote to close such questions as "typo" (when you have gained the privilege). these questions should not be blessed with an Answer.  comments are a good idea... but you were a little late to the party. a dozen people already figured the issue out in the comments.

Comment: While the information in this answer is true, it wouldn't cause the reported error.